# How do I fix a infinite while loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that uses a while loop to receive multiple inputs in the form.

The function compares

id, C for add or D for remove, and amount to add/remove by

951482 C 5.250

951482 D 15.111

951482 C 29.628

951482 D 10.200

951482 D 3.175

951482 X ‐1

The function compares these lines to an input received somewhere else

id, charge(ignore this), limit of data, and starting data

951482 6.25 50 35.733

changes are preformed on the starting data

Where the last line is the end of my loop

I currently have

```
    void read_and_total (bool& any_errors, double& starting_disk_usage,
                     double& max_disk_usage, double& end_disk_usage,
                     int& account_number)
{
    int line_account;
    double data_change;
    char transaction_char;
    int line_number = 2;

    end_disk_usage = starting_disk_usage;
    max_disk_usage = starting_disk_usage;


    cin >> line_account >> transaction_char >> data_change;

    any_errors = false;

    while (account_number != line_account && transaction_char != 'X' && data_change != -1)
    {
        cout << line_account << ' ' <<  transaction_char << ' ' << data_change      << endl;
        if (transaction_char == 'D')
            end_disk_usage =  end_disk_usage - data_change;

        if (transaction_char == 'C')
            end_disk_usage = end_disk_usage + data_change;

        if (max_disk_usage < end_disk_usage)
            max_disk_usage = end_disk_usage;

        //Error proccessing
        if (transaction_char != 'C' && transaction_char != 'D' &&
                transaction_char != 'X')
        {
                cout << "Error in line #" << line_number << " - "
                     << "invalid transaction code" << ' ' << transaction_char
                     << ' ' << endl;
                any_errors = true;
        }
        if (data_change < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error in line #" << line_number << " - "
                 << "invalid transaction amount " << data_change << endl;
            any_errors = true;
        }
        if (line_account != account_number) {
            cout << "Error in line #" << line_number << " - "
                 << " non‐matching account number" << line_account
                 << endl;
            any_errors = true;
        }
        cout << "Bottom of function" << endl;
        cin >> line_account >> transaction_char >> data_change;
    }

    return;
    }
```

My while loop is infinitely looping due to the control variable not updating, I don't understand why this is happening because I asking for a new character and new double.

Edit 6:

Ok it actually does not work still however the error in my while statement has been brought to light I want to compare account_number and line_account, this is my fault for using bad variable names.

so when I used one of the solutions

```
while(account_number != line_account && transaction_char != 'X' && data_change != -1)
```

it does not enter the loop as it is always false, and skips over the rest of the numbers

my while loops is testing for this line

```
951482 X ‐1
```

where the line_account number is the same as my account_number
the character is X
and the value is exactly -1

when I remove the checking for the account_number it works but with it added it always fails to enter the loop.

Edit 4:

I added additional info on the problem at the top

i want my while loop to check for this line at the end of my data

951482 X ‐1

and all three values must be correct, 
account number should be the same as the header
the character should be x 
and the value MUST be -1 not any other negative value.

Edit 3:

i have now change my while statement to

```
while (!(account_number == line_number && transaction_char == 'X' && data_change == -1))
```

I believe this is the source of my problems I am trying to get all three conditions to be true for the loop to end.

Edit 2:

After adding 2 test ouputs the resulting message is a repition of

```
Bottom of function
951482 X 0.000000
```

I am not sure why -1 is being set to 0.00000

Edit:

If a include a test statement at the end of the while loop it results in infinitely printing statement. I think I have a problem in my while loop conditions.

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: It's because there's an error in the input file somewhere, and `std::cin` enters failed state, and all subsequent `>>` operators fail, and do change the variables. Solution: don't use `>>` to parse error-prone input.

Comment: Sometimes double comparisons don't work so try data_change > -1.

Comment: Print out the three variables `line_account` `transaction_char` and `data_change` as the very first thing in your while loop

Comment: BTW, you keep reading if the transaction letter isn't C, D, or X.  You may want to have an `else` clause so you don't process the invalid lines.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it has a problem reading the last line if it doesn't have a final newline character ('\n'). Try adding one to the data file and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is there any reason your loop can't just be `while(transaction_char != 'X')`

Comment: The way your loop is written, all the statements must be false.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect

```
while (!(account_number == line_number && transaction_char == 'X' && data_change == -1))
```

should be

```
while (account_number != line_number || transaction_char != 'X' || data_change != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing your `while()` statement to:

```
while(account_number != line_number && transaction_char != 'X' && data_change != -1))
{
  :
  :
}
```